# How to undertand Git's command syntax?

Tags: git, version-control

As Windows user, I am learning Git using [Version Control with Git](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008Y4OR3A) and [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book). Unfortunately, none of the books, nor the Git official manual, explain how to correctly build/write Git commands. Is there a guide for Git's command syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git’s built in documentation is fantastic. Most questions can usually be resolved like this example

```
git commit --help
```

This will bring up the Manual page for that command. These pages are extremely verbose and will typically have sections

```
NAME
SYNOPSIS
DESCRIPTION
OPTIONS
EXAMPLES
DISCUSSION
ENVIRONMENT AND CONFIGURATION VARIABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't imagine/predict full correct syntax for Git commands
2. Manual (in form of `git help <COMMAND>`) **is a MUST, all time, all cases**